# Failed to connect to your instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

```
Failed to connect to your instance
EC2 Instance Connect is  unable to connect to your instance.
Ensure your instance network settings are configured correctly for EC2 Instance Connect. 
For more information, see EC2 Instance Connect Prerequisites at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-prerequisites.html.
```

I have an Ubuntu EC2, the instance was working perfectly fine yesterday but now I cannot enter. I also tried to put in Inbound rules SSH 0.0.0.0 (To allow every single IP but it still did not work) I cannot enter, I tried to restart but still not working.

However, the server endpoints are working perfectly fine.

I cannot also run this command because I cannot get inside the instance

```
sudo apt-get install ec2-instance-connect
```

I tried to run through SSH(terminal) and cannot access it there either (Connection timeout).

Comment: When you try to SSH to it directly (instead of using EC2 Instance Connect), does it fail immediately or does it take several seconds before failing? You can request debug information by using `ssh -vvv ...`. You can use "Get system log" and "Get instance screenshot" in the EC2 console (under Actions/Monitor and troubleshoot) to see what might be happening.

Comment: Thats the log : debug1: Connecting to host.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com [IP] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:000001E28DCE9CB0
debug1: connect to address IP port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host HOST.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out @JohnRotenstein

Comment: A timeout indicates no network connectivity. Is the instance in a **public subnet**? If the security group permits the access, then it should work (unless the software on the instance is bad). Use "Get system log" to see what it is doing.